# How to improve the performance of this code?

Tags: c, performance, vectorization, biginteger, processing-efficiency

I'm writing a program which operates with arrays of Big Integer Numbers and does basic operations. 
I'm worried about the performance of my code. It executes in 47 seconds when compiled with:

```
gcc -Ofast -funroll-all-loops -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec -g -lm $1 -o ${2}.Ofast
```

I thought the key to solving my problem is changing the data type of my arrays to `unsigned long long`, but when I do the result is different.

Any suggestion is welcome, even if it changes my whole program or data types as long as it doesn't change the outcome of my program.

Also, I have been able to visualize that my performance problem is mainly in the `LongNumAddition` and `LongNumAddDigit` functions, how can I improve my code? Thanks for your attention.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
// Variable used to generate pseudo-random numbers
unsigned int seed;
unsigned int temp;
unsigned int var1 = 214013;
unsigned int var2 = 2531011;
#define val13 13
#define ten 10

// Function to generate pseudo-random numbers
inline int myRandom() {
  temp = var1*seed;
  seed = temp + var2;
  return (seed>>val13);
}

void LongNumInit( uint8_t *L, size_t N )
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    L[i] = myRandom() % 10;
  }

}

void LongNumPrint( uint8_t *L, size_t N, uint8_t *Name )
{
  printf("%s:", Name);
  for ( size_t i=N; i>0;--i )
  {
    printf("%d", L[i-1]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void LongNumSet( uint8_t *L, size_t N){
    memset(L,0,N);
}


void LongNumCopy( const uint8_t *Vin, uint8_t *Vout, size_t N )
{
  memcpy(Vout,Vin,N);
}
uint8_t LongNumAddition( uint8_t *Vin1, uint8_t *Vin2,uint8_t *Vout, size_t N)
{
  uint8_t CARRY = 0;

  for ( size_t i=0; i< N; ++i )
  {

        Vout[i] = Vin1[i] + Vin2[i] + CARRY;
        CARRY = (Vout[i] > 9);
        if(CARRY){
           Vout[i] -= ten;
        }
      }
  return CARRY;
}


uint8_t LongNumAddDigit( uint8_t *V, uint8_t digit, size_t N )
{
  size_t i=0;
  V[0] += digit;

  if ( V[0] < ten){
        return 0;
  }
  V[0] -=ten;

  // add carry, maybe iteratively for all digits

  while ((++i < N) && (V[i] >= 9))
  {
    V[i] = 0;
  }
  if((i != N) && (V[i] < 9)){
    V[i]++;
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

uint8_t LongNumHorizAdd( uint8_t *Vin, uint8_t *Vout, size_t N )
{
  uint8_t CARRY = 0;
  LongNumSet ( Vout, N);
  for ( size_t i=0; i< N; ++i )
  {
    LongNumAddDigit ( Vout, Vin[i], N );

  }

  return 0; // CARRY can never be set
}
uint8_t LongNumConstMult( uint8_t *V, size_t N, uint8_t digit )
{
  uint8_t CARRY = 0;
  for ( size_t i=0; i< N; ++i )
  {
    V[i] = V[i] * digit + CARRY;
    CARRY = ((u_int32_t)V[i] * (u_int32_t)0xCCCD) >> 19;
    V[i] -= (CARRY << 3) + (CARRY << 1);
  }
  return CARRY; // may be from 0 to 9
}
void LongNumMultiply( uint8_t *Vin1, uint8_t *Vin2, uint8_t *VoutH, uint8_t *VoutL, size_t N)
{

  // Create Temporal Long Integer with double size
  uint8_t *TEMP = (uint8_t*) malloc(2*N*sizeof(uint8_t));
  uint8_t *RES = (uint8_t*) malloc( 2*N*sizeof(uint8_t));

  LongNumSet  ( RES, 2*N);    // Set RES to 0

  for ( size_t i=0; i<N; ++i )
  {
    LongNumSet  ( TEMP, 2*N);            // Set TEMP to 0
    LongNumCopy ( Vin1, TEMP+i, N );         // Copy Vin1 -> TEMP, with offset i
    LongNumConstMult( TEMP, 2*N, Vin2[i] );  // TEMP * Vin2[i] -> TEMP
    LongNumAddition ( TEMP, RES, RES, 2*N ); // TEMP + RES -> RES
  }

  // Result goes to VoutH-VoutL
  LongNumCopy ( RES,   VoutL, N );  // Copy RES   -> VoutL
  LongNumCopy ( RES+N, VoutH, N );  // Copy RES+N -> VoutH
}
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i, sum1, sum2, sum3, N=10000, Rep=50;

  seed = 12345;

  // obtain parameters at run time
  if (argc>1) { N    = atoi(argv[1]); }
  if (argc>2) { Rep  = atoi(argv[2]); }
  printf("Challenge #3: Vector size is %d. Repeat %d times\n", N, Rep);
 // Create Long Nums
  unsigned char *V1= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );
  unsigned char *V2= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );
  unsigned char *V3= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );
  unsigned char *V4= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );

  LongNumInit ( V1, N ); LongNumInit ( V2, N ); LongNumInit ( V3, N );
   // Repeat
  for (i=0; i<Rep; i++)
  {
    LongNumAddition ( V1, V2, V4, N );
    LongNumMultiply ( V3, V4, V2, V1, N );
    LongNumHorizAdd ( V1, V2, N );
    LongNumAddDigit ( V3, V2[0], N );
  }

  // Print last 32 digits of Long Numbers
  LongNumPrint( V1, 32, "V1" );
 LongNumPrint( V2, 32, "V2" );
  LongNumPrint( V3, 32, "V3" );
  LongNumPrint( V4, 32, "V4" );

  free(V1); free(V2); free(V3); free(V4);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is way to broad. Use a profiler to find out what takes most time and then focus on that part. Also, indent your code properly. It's ok-ish, but it should look nicer when you post.

Comment: Note that `-ffast-math` only affects floating point, which your program doesn't use.

Comment: That is to say that a good way to optimize my code would be to use intrisic functions and write part of the code with instructions in assembly? So is it not necessary to change my data type to unsigned long long? Also, I am writting this for an exercice.
@NateEldredge

Comment: This question is a superset of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062060/why-compiler-doesnt-vectorize-this-function which has unresolved comments. Please address  those before starting the next question (with essentially the same problem).

Comment: You might note that `LongNumMultiply()` allocates memory that is neither returned to the calling function nor freed — it leaks! Your code using `LongNumAdd()` ignores the carry; in general, you're producing the wrong answer (though not always). It's odd to insist that the two numbers have the same length — multiplying `3` by `300,000,000,000` is not unreasonable, but forcing `3` to 12 digits isn't obvious. You might be better off with a structure characterizing each number — that could include allocated length as well as active length, and maybe a sign too (how do you handle negative numbers)?

Comment: If the code works and you are just looking for general performance optimization, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better site to ask.

Comment: The posted code does not CLEANLY compile!  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )   Since the code is working with large numbers and converting `int` values to a single char value, and for other reasons, The code (most likely) is not producing the correct result.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after ever opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) Please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3)  Please use meaningful variable names.  Names like `v1` `v2`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: OT: regarding: `unsigned char *V1= (unsigned char*) malloc( N*sizeof(unsigned char) );` and similar statements: 1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.  2)  The expression: `sizeof( unsigned char ) is always 1.  multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect (except for cluttering the code)  Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: OT: regarding: `#define val13 13` and `#define ten 10`  By convention, `#define`d names are all capitals and root words separated via underscores.

Comment: Suggest, rather than the function:  `myRandom()`  to use `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );` to initialize the random number generator and then obtain each random value via a call to: `rand()`

Comment: regarding: `while ((++i < N) && (V[i] >= 9))
  {
    V[i] = 0;
  }`  This seems to be replacing any digit that is >9 with 0 with no regard to `carry` operations, etc.  Probably not what you want to do.

Comment: I tried to apply your suggestion about substitute the function myRandom() with srand and rand but it gives me the wrong end result @user3629249

Comment: how do you know what the 'right result' consists of?

Answer (score 2):

Use a profiler - strongly recommend kcachegrind

https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Usage.html

first, install valgrind and kcachegrind, then compile your binary using '-g' using gcc, and then run your binary using

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./yourbinary parameters ...
```

then, run kcachgrind in the current directory, switch view to display line-by-line timing information, like this

https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/Shot4Large.html

this tells you which lines of your code took most of the runtime.